# Check Box Event onCheckChanged : Event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am using a CheckBox like this:

### ASPX

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbCode" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbCode_CheckedChanged" />
```

### C#

```
protected void cbCode_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Convert.ToBoolean(cbCode.Checked))
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

The event is not firing and I'm unable to find out what is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `AutoPostBack="True"` on your checkbox.

Comment: :D I was using update panel and this property was missing . Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trigger for checkbox checkchanged underneath content of updatepanel.